# add gitlab-ci job when including an gitlab-ci template

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

here is my problem:
I have a GitLab-ci.yml template in a separate repository with all basic stages/steps in it. In another repo with the actual code, I include that template and overwrite a variable for unit testing for example.

Here is how the base template looks like:

```
---
image: docker:git

variables:
  TEST_CMD: unit-test $UNIT_TEST_CMD_OPTIONS

stages:
  - pre-build
  - build
  - test

actual_build:
  stage: build
  <<: *only-default
  script:
    - echo "build it"
    - ...

....
```

Now I include that template into my actual repo gitlab-ci.yml file to execute the whole pipeline:

```
---
include:
  - project: blahfubar/gitlab-ci-template
    ref: master
    file: basic.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  UNIT_TEST_CMD_OPTIONS: --testsuite unit
```

Now the problem:
I want to add an extra job just in this repo to i.e. execute a security check there, but this does not work and with the "extends:"-keyword only jobs can be extended.

```
---
include:
  - project: blahfubar/gitlab-ci-template
    ref: master
    file: basic.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  UNIT_TEST_CMD_OPTIONS: --testsuite unit

security-step:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./security-check
```

If I do it like that, only the "security-step" will be executed, but not all the other steps from the included template.

May anyone has a solution for that because I didn't find anything in the gitlab-ci docs.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `!reference` keyword in Gitlab may help you, but probably not fully resolve your issue: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

Your `security-step` could look like this:

```yaml
security-step:
  stage: test
  script:
    - !reference [actual_build, script]
    - ./security-check
```

This will include all your build script lines before the security step.